# pgfplots: hide plot border (but not ticks and grid)

Tags: pgfplots

I'm quite new to using pgfplots, and trying to figure out if there is a way to remove the border around the plot while at the same time keeping the axis ticks, labels and grid. Is this possible? Using `hide axis` will hide all those things making the plot float in "mid-air", which is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe `axis line style={draw=none}`?

Comment: Does esdd's trick answer your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.